# Lazy load not working with filtrify and Isotope

Tags: jquery, filter, lazy-loading

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $("ul#container img").lazyload({ 
        event : "mouseover",
        effect : "fadeIn"
    });

    var container = $("#container");

   container.isotope({
        itemSelector : 'ul#container > li',
        layoutMode : 'masonry'
    });


  var ft =  $.filtrify("container", "placeHolder", {
        block    : "data-original",
        hide     : false,
        close    : true,
        callback : function ( query, match, mismatch ) {
          /*
        Extend jQuery with an "inview" selector to 
        select elements that are in the visible
        part of the page (at least partiacialy) 
    */
    $.extend($.expr[':'],{
        inview: function(el) {
            var e = $(el),
                w = $(window),
                wt = w.scrollTop(),
                wb = wt + w.height(),
                et = e.offset().top,
                eb = et + e.height();

            return ( (eb >= wt) && (et <= wb) );
        }
    });
     $("ul#container img").lazyload({ 
        event : "scroll filter",
        effect : "fadeIn"
    });
    $(match).find("img:inview").trigger("filter");
            container.isotope({ filter : $(match) });
            if ( mismatch.length ) $("div#reset").show();
            else $("div#reset").hide();
             }
    });
    $("div#reset span").click(function() {
        ft.reset();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: After we apply a filter, the results that come up, has main src image, and is not replaced by data-original image, as it should do with lazyload, although when I scroll down to the page, lazyload seems to work fine, its just the custom trigger event "filter" that does not seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Looked through the lazyload code. If "scroll" is anywhere in the event it ignores everything else.
Initially I did a page scroll trigger. But I had a css issue where the windows thinks the image was in it's original location. So it thought it was off the page. :(

I did notice however that lazyload will always run on event "appear".
So changing

```
$(match).find("img:inview").trigger("filter");
```

to

```
$(match).find("img:inview").trigger("appear");
```

will work. Though it will force all $(match) images to load even if they aren't visible.
Not best solution I know.  But...